# Multilevel XSD constraint

Tags: xml, xsd

we are trying to get model a good for our XSD at the moment. Here is the issue:

```
List
 I-> Item1
       I->Element1
       I->Element2
       I->Element3       
 I-> Item2
       I->Element1
       I->Element2
       I->Element3
 I-> Item3
       I->Element1
       I->Element2
       I->Element3

ReferenceToElement
 I-> Item1/Element1
```

We got a model were we need two nested lists. So there is a List with "items" and each item has a list with elements. So we want to reference these elements.

**First approach**

Each item/element does have a number property. The number property is unique within all items. Additionally the number property is unique across all elements in the way that the number of the parent item is encoded with its number. For example for item.no = 2 all elements will look like this 2xx, so 201, 202 etc. This ofcourse will limit the elements to 100 which is fine for us.

In order to maintain existance of the elements referenced, we created a constraint over all items to be unique as well as all elements across all items. So our reference to a element will look like this

```
Reference
  - ItemNo
  - ElementNo
```

This way we ensured the item as well as the element exists. I know there is an issue between these two fiels, because the referenced item doesn't necessarily is implicitly stated in the elementno. For example ItemNo=1, but ElementNo=202. This way a schema validation will tell us at least if these elements does exist. The major drawback is that we need to take care of the correct assignment of the number in all elements which kills us right now.

**Second approach**

We will not use the constraint on the elementNo but stay with the itemNo. That way we can use the simple numbers on all elements, but we will loose the reference itegrity on the elementNo during schema validation. This seems the best way for us right now.

**Question:**

Is there a way to model a two staged reference with XSD capabilities? I read something about asserts but it doesn't seem to help us in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

[*Note that it would be a little easier to understand your question if you actually showed some XML.  As it is, any answer will have to based in part on guesswork about what XML constructs your prose description is intended to describe; take them, then, with a grain of salt.*]

If I understand you, you wish to impose several constraints (numbered here for reference):

1. Each `<element>` element appears as a child of an `<item>` element.
2. Each `<element>` and `<item>` element has a `number` attribute whose value is an identifying number; the value of each `number` attribute is a finite sequence of decimal digits.
3. The identifying number of each `<item>` element is unique across all `<item>` elements in some identified container element (e.g. the document element).
4. The identifying number of each `<element>` element is unique across all `<element>` elements in the same container element.  (Or perhaps you mean that it is unique across all `<element>` elements within the containing item?  I can't tell from your description.)
5. The identifying number of each `<element>` element will have the identifying number of the parent `<item>` element as a prefix.
6. The identifying number of each `<element>` element will be exactly two digits longer than the identifying number of the parent `<item>` element.

The following schema imposes these constraints.  Since you mention assertions, I assume you are able to work with XSD 1.1.  (If you don't have 1.1, you don't have assertions.)

```
<xs:schema 
    targetNamespace="http://example.com/elements-and-items"
    xmlns:tns="http://example.com/elements-and-items"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:element name="test" type="tns:test">
    <xs:unique name="item-unique">
      <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation>
          Ensure that the number attribute on each
          item is unique within the 'test' element.
          (Enforces constraint 3.)
        </xs:documentation>
      </xs:annotation>
      <xs:selector xpath=".//tns:item"/>
      <xs:field xpath="@number"/>
    </xs:unique>
    <xs:unique name="element-unique">
      <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation>
          Ensure that the number attribute on each
          item is unique within the 'test' element.
          (Enforces constraint 4.  If 'element' elements
          are only supposed to be unique within 'item'
          elements, then move this to the declaration of
          the 'item' element, and forget constraint
          5.)                    
        </xs:documentation>
      </xs:annotation>
      <xs:selector xpath=".//tns:item/tns:element"/>
      <xs:field xpath="@number"/>
    </xs:unique>

  </xs:element>

  <xs:element name="item" type="tns:item"/>

  <xs:element name="element" type="tns:element"/>

  <xs:complexType name="test">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation>
        Each 'test' element contains a sequence of
        'item' elements.
        (Helps enforce constraint 1.)
      </xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element ref="tns:item" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>        
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="item">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation>
        Each 'item' element contains a sequence of
        'element' elements.
        (Helps enforce constraint 1.)
        Each 'item' element has a 'number' attribute,
        of type 'tns:number'.
        (Enforces constraint 2 for 'item' elements.)
      </xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element ref="tns:element" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="number" type="tns:number"/>
    <xs:assert test="
        every $id in ./@number satisfies
        every $e in .//tns:element/@number satisfies
        starts-with($e,$id)">
      <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation>
          Each element-identifying number has the
          item-identifying number of the containing item
          as a prefix.
          Enforces constraint 5.
        </xs:documentation>
      </xs:annotation>
    </xs:assert>
    <xs:assert test="
        every $id in ./@number satisfies
        every $e in .//tns:element/@number satisfies
        string-length($e) = string-length($id) + 2">
      <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation>
          Each element-identifying number is two
          digits longer than the item-identifying
          number of the containing item.
          Enforces constraint 6.
        </xs:documentation>
      </xs:annotation>
    </xs:assert>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="element" mixed="true">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation>
        Each 'element' element has a 'number' attribute,
        of type 'tns:number'.
        (Enforces constraint 2 for 'element' elements.)
      </xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:sequence/>
    <xs:attribute name="number" type="tns:number"/>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:simpleType name="number">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:pattern value="\d+"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

Note that every XSD 1.1 processor is required to support a rather minimal subset of XPath 2.0 in assertions; I have made no effort to try to write the assertions here within that subset (but neither have I made any effort to decide whether they can or cannot be written in that subset).

A valid instance, structurally identical (as far as I can tell) to your non-XML example:

```
<test xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://example.com/elements-and-items 
    uniqueness.xsd"
 xmlns="http://example.com/elements-and-items">

  <item number="1">
    <element number="101"/>
    <element number="102"/>
    <element number="103"/>
  </item>
  <item number="2">
    <element number="201"/>
    <element number="205"/>
    <element number="206"/>
  </item>
  <item number="3">
    <element number="303"/>
    <element number="301"/>
    <element number="302"/>
  </item>

</test>
```

An invalid instance illustrating each constraint by violating it; if the schema is doing its job, each violation should be detected and should make the appropriate element or item invalid:

```
<test xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://example.com/elements-and-items
    uniqueness.xsd"
 xmlns="http://example.com/elements-and-items">

  <item number="1">
    <element number="101"/>
    <element number="102"/>
    <element number="103"/>
  </item>
  <item number="1">
    <!--* duplicate item number, invalid
        * (violates constraint 3) 
        *-->
    <element number="104"/>
    <element number="105"/>
    <element number="106"/>
  </item>
  <item number="2">
    <element number="107">
      element number unique but doesn't match item number 
      (violates constraint 5)
    </element>
    <element number="202"/>
    <element number="202">
      item number not unique
      (violates constraint 4)
    </element>
  </item>
  <item number="3">
    <element number="303"/>
    <element number="301"/>
    <element number="3141592">
      item number unique and matches item number
      but more than two digits longer 
      (violates constraint 6)</element>
  </item>

</test>
```